# OpenCV 2.4.11 SVM predict() slightly different output depending on architecture?

Tags: c++, opencv, floating-point, svm

I have a trained SVM model.

I am calling predict with the same model and the same Mat.  I am running the same code on my Android device and via a small C++ program compiled natively on my Mac.

I am verifying the float values in the Mat are the same via this code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < featureVector.cols; j++) {
    float val = featureVector.at<float>(0,j);
    qDebug() << QString::number(val, 'g', 9);
}

float pred = svm.predict(featureVector.reshape(1,1), true);
```

However, the outputs are always different on the two different architectures with the same inputs.  Is this expected?

Sample prediction outputs:

Android - 2.86143899

Mac - 2.86144328

The differences in output appear to be on the border of floating point precision.  Perhaps the precision is being impacted by various handling of intermediates inside of SVM?  Is there a way to get the same outputs?

I've tried rounding to various levels of precision on the input side and still get different outputs when I run the same code on these two different platforms.

Comment: "Is this expected?" Yes. However, this difference is not that bad for svm prediction. You will probably use a threshold with much lower precision.

Comment: @DimChtz - ""Is this expected?" Yes." Why?  Are there any workarounds to get exact same outputs?

Comment: platform optimization and parallelism maybe?